# How to integrate AngularJS in a Symfony2 Bundle in HTML5 URL mode.?

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony

I am currently learning Symfony2 and so far I really like the framework. However, I have a situation that I don't know how to solve.

I have a Symfony2 application that has two bundles: Frontend (prefix: /) and Admin (prefix: /admin; this prefix is changeable). Now, I am trying to add AngularJS application in HTML5 mode (the URLs don't have a hash).

Here is how I want to achieve this:

1. Create a "sub-bundle" that will have the following prefix: /admin/_api. Here are two examples on how they will look like: `POST /admin/_api/users` or `GET /admin/_api/users/10`
2. Create a 404 page in Admin bundle that will load the AngularJS template.

The reason for doing this is simple. When I open the path `/admin/users/10` *for the first time*, the AdminBundle error page will open the AngularJS template. And AngularJS router will route `/admin/users/10` to the necessary controller. Then, the AngularJS controller will make a request to `GET /admin/_api/users/10` and send the returned JSON data from the server to the AngularJS view.

For the first problem, even if the solution is not the most elegant one, I can add prefixes in the AppBundle's configuration. But my main problem is the second one. How can I create a bundle based error page?